# method setRolloverEnabled unexpected behavior.

Tags: java, swing

I have this three images that should cycle on click, while i get  the gif image when i click, the other two images dont respond, they still change on mouse roll over.
I have set the setRolloverEnabled method to false to stop my images from changing on mouse roll over but they continue to change. Im unable to spot my error,  could someone point out my mistake.

```
public class ImageButton extends JFrame {

    private final JButton imgButton;
    private final Icon clickImage;

    public ImageButton() {
        super("Lab button");

        Icon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imageBtn/Images/Image1.png"));
        Icon image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imageBtn/Images/Image2.png"));
        clickImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imageBtn/Images/Image3.gif"));

        imgButton = new JButton(image1);
        imgButton.setRolloverIcon(image2);
        add(imgButton);
        ButtonClickEventHandler buttonEventHandler = new ButtonClickEventHandler();
        imgButton.addActionListener(buttonEventHandler);

    }   

    private class ButtonClickEventHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {         

            imgButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
            imgButton.setIcon(clickImage);
        }


    }
```

import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class ImageButtonApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageButton image = new ImageButton();
        image.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        image.setSize(660, 660);
        image.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work okay for me (once the button is clicked, the rollover image is no longer displayed when moving the mouse through the button)

Comment: that's  odd, are you able to to click through the 3 images? i can only click once as the second image does not appear on click, why would the rollover capability shows up at all. The fact that its set to false should disable it entirely correct?

Comment: When I click it, it switches to the third image and does not change - but I wasn't using a gif